# Can I use a chinese s2 visa for tourism?

Tags: visas, china

A few years ago, a friend in China invited me to spend a significant amount of time with his family. I applied for a 10 year tourist visa, using his letter of invitation and one of his family's houses for where I would stay. The embassy gave me an S2 visa instead, which I used several times that year.

Now, I would like to take a vacation to China. I won't be seeing my friend. My S2 visa is still valid. Can I use it or do I need to apply for a new tourist visa?

Answer (score 1):

S2 visa is issued to those who intend to visit their family members who are foreigners working or studying in China, or to those who intend to go to China for other private matters.

You will need a Type-L visa for tourism.

Comment: this is an example where a link or citation could be extremely useful, if you get a chance